# how to read variables from .bash_profile and PATH in ansible

Tags: ansible

I have the   `./bash_profile`   in CentOS 7,  in that `.bash_profile` many exported variables, when I put it into ansible playbook:

```
  tasks:
    - shell: . /home/dbadmin/.bash_profile && [ MY COMMAND ]
      register: PRO

    - debug: var=PRO
```

when I execute it it does not display those variables that I need to pass later also, how I can export `$PATH` in playbook:

```
 echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/root/bin:/root/.local/bin:/root/bin:/root/.local/bin:/root/bin:/root/.local/bin:/root/bin
```

Comment: Question is not clear enough. Why do you need to source the `bash_profile` ? and what does it mean by "it does not display those variable that...." ?

Comment: inside the regular shell script we use the exported variables form   .bash_profile , I need to do the same in ansible playbook

Comment: ok, and what to you meany by "it does not display those variable that...." ?

Comment: I need to use variables from .bash-profile like:               export  TZ=<time zone>    export UIDPassword=upass        export admpassword=admpass       and so forth

Comment: `su - idbadmin -c 'echo $admpassword' `try this.

Comment: it did not work, I got the blank in output

Comment: things are not adding up. If you do `. /home/dbadmin/.bash_profile && echo $anyVarOfBashProfile`  it should work! it may be issue when one of the variable is having some special character in it. so you might want to quote entire input to shell like `". /home/dbadmin/.bash_profile && echo $anyVarOfBashProfile"`